# python child class method calling overridden classmethod with non-classmethod

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do the following in python3:

```py
class Parent:
    @classmethod
    def show(cls, message):
        print(f'{message}')

    @classmethod
    def ask(cls, message):
        cls.show(f'{message}???')

class Child(Parent):
    @property
    def name(self):
        return 'John'

    def show(self, message):
        print(f'{self.name}: {message}')

instance = Child()
instance.ask('what')
```

But it then complains

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in ask
TypeError: Child.show() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

even so `child.show` works as expected. So it seems that `child.ask` is calling `Parent.show`... I tried to mark `Child.show` as classmethod too, but then the `cls.name` is not showing the expected output:

```py
class Child2(Parent):
    @property
    def name(self):
        return 'John'

    @classmethod
    def show(cls, message):
        print(f'{cls.name}: {message}')

instance2 = Child2()
instance2.ask('what')
```

this shows

```
<property object at 0xfc7b90>: what???
```

Is there a way to override a parent classmethod with a non-classmethod, but keeping other parent classmethod to call the overridden one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it hard to follow for the second half of the question but there was an issue I saw and it might help you solve your problem.

When you said `even so child.show works as expected. So it seems that child.ask is calling Parent.show`, thats not what is happening.

When you called `instance.ask("what")`, it called the @classmethod decorated method of the `Child` class (which is inherited from the parent). This `ask` method is passing the class `Child` as the first argument, (not the instance you created). This means the line

```
cls.show(f'{message}???')
```

is equivalent to

```
Child.show(f'{message}???') # because cls is the Class not the instance
```

The show method inside the `Child` class is an instance method and expects the first argument to be the actual instance (`self`) but the string `f'{message}???'` is being passed to it and it expects a second message string to be passed so that's why its is throwing an error.

Hope this helped

Comment: Indeed... It was my misunderstanding... So I have found a way to achieve my goal without classmethods and did a dirty trick where it was needed (unittest)...